# Python exercise to find root/power integer pair for a user entered integer

Tags: python

Here is the exercise as it was written:

Finger exercise: Write a program that asks the user to enter an `integer` and prints two `integers`, `root` and `pwr`, such that `1 < pwr < 6` and `root**pwr` is equal to the integer entered by the user. If no such pair of integers exists, it should print a message to that effect.

And this is what I came up with:

```
    num_value = int(input("Enter a number value:"))
    result_state = "unknown"
    for root in range (-abs(num_value),abs(num_value)):
        for pwr in range(2,6):
            test_value = root**pwr
            if test_value == num_value:
                print(f'{num_value} is equivalent to {root} to the power of {pwr}')
                result_state = "Printed"
    if result_state != "Printed":
        print('I was not able to find a root/power integer pair for this number.')
```

The code I wrote worked, but I feel like there's probably a more effecient way to achieve the same result. I also definitly feel like I may have fudged it a bit by adding the absolute functions for the root range.  I'm trying to learn python on my own using OpenCourseware, but I want to make sure that I don't develop blindspots in my understanding. So thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Your `root` range is asymmetrical, in that the negative of the minimum is larger than the maximum (since `range(a, b)` includes `a` but excludes `b`).

Comment: Geez I gotta turn my brain on. I corrected it in the pwr range (for the very reason that I didn't want it to include 1 so I had the range start at 2) but my silly little self took a short cut because I figured all the valid root inputs wouldn't include the number itself (since 1 is excluded from the acceptable pwr values) but I didn't stop to think if a user entered 1 as the num_value. So note to self, no lazy shortcuts. Thank you!

Comment: If there's more than one answer, which do you want?  16 for example can be `2**4` or `4**2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some improvement of your code:

1. Change `result_state` from `string` to `boolean`. The comparison of boolean is faster than comprison of string.
2. Change the range of `root` from `range(-abs(num_value),abs(num_value))` to `range(-sqrt_num, sqrt_num + 1)`. Since the smallest `pwr` is 2, if `root` is greater than the square root of `abs(num_value)`, `test_value` cannot equal to `num_value`.
3. Add `break` to `if-statement`, if a pair of `root` and `pwr`, when `root` grows, `test_value` cannot still equals to `num_value`.

Here is the updated code:

```py
num_value = int(input("Enter a number value: "))
result_state = False
sqrt_num = int(abs(num_value) ** 0.5)

for root in range(-sqrt_num, sqrt_num + 1):
    for pwr in range(2, 6):
        test_value = root ** pwr
        if test_value == num_value:
            print(f'{num_value} is equivalent to {root} to the power of {pwr}')
            result_state = True
            break  # Exit inner loop if pair found

if result_state != True:
    print('I was not able to find a root/power integer pair for this number.')
```

Comment: By using floating point math for an integer problem, you're (1) risking floating point error and (2) restricting the range of the integers to those that can be accurately represented as floats (after which floating point error will again arise).

Comment: These are fantastic suggestions, thank you! Boolean is definitely the right call for result_state. (I definitely need to make sure I don't fall into a bad habit of using strings for everything.)

Comment: I can see what your doing with the square root function to help reduce how many integers it's checking for the root range. Is there a way to accomplish something similar without introducing potential errors like Tom said. I played around with it, adding the break also makes sense except for cases where the user inputs values like -1, 0, or 1.

Comment: *"The comparison of boolean is faster than comprison of string"* - That's really really insignificant and irrelevant. It's a *single* comparison of short strings, among much more other work.

Comment: You only `break` out of the inner loop, which is very short anyway. You'd better stop the *whole* search instead.

Answer (score 0):

With [Heron's / Newton's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Heron%27s_method) method to compute the p-th root of n:

```py
def root_and_pwr(n):
    if n >= 0:
        sign = +1
        P = range(2, 6)
    else:
        n = -n
        sign = -1
        P = range(3, 6, 2)
    for p in P:
        r = n
        q = p - 1
        while r**p > n:
            r = (q*r + n//r**q) // p
        if r**p == n:
            return sign*r, p
    return None, None
```

Usage demo:

```
for n in range(-100, 101):
    root, pwr = root_and_pwr(n)
    if root is not None:
        print(f'{n} = {root}^{pwr}')

print(root_and_pwr(3141592653589793238462643383279 ** 5))
```

Output of that ([Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bZJNboMwEIXVLad4uwAB8eNAoBI5QpUTNIoUkyBFgzFEqEKcpJts2kP1MFVtIEFN64WtGc_39GY075_irTmVdL1-XJrcTb6evg88hyzLZrenw0600iTr2YA6RQ7CJoM_hvrUxZGQYRncM1sVyj0duRk6iK0hz881nxkNuPQo4f4nwZSEg3BUyUsJgYKwnbWkKp2lKhUJuJil2lNx5pC2LbABzdyNNStbYgnyPFVTWfA8iHuR6ncgs-wPypuLpMG6LZ0JmZIvJXFnuA1DWyZteWzHDXzfQeAH00D1lBXdaicPE78NXKdR1CD1aM3Zh5AFNWa-6KhXeKcL-9dO0f3CMozx95coC1ZBlIZxxKIkXacsZMkqDuMVYwkL1ylsG5FljWswbcNtK34A)):

```
-64 = -4^3
-32 = -2^5
-27 = -3^3
-8 = -2^3
-1 = -1^3
0 = 0^2
1 = 1^2
4 = 2^2
8 = 2^3
9 = 3^2
16 = 4^2
25 = 5^2
27 = 3^3
32 = 2^5
36 = 6^2
49 = 7^2
64 = 8^2
81 = 9^2
100 = 10^2
(3141592653589793238462643383279, 5)
```

And for input/output like you specified:

```
num_value = int(input("Enter a number value:"))
root, pwr = root_and_pwr(num_value)
if root is not None:
    print(f'{num_value} is equivalent to {root} to the power of {pwr}')
else:
    print('I was not able to find a root/power integer pair for this number.')
```

It's a good idea to separate input/output from computation. Having the pure computation in a function makes the code cleaner and easier to test. For example, you could write your solution in a similar function and the other answer's in a third, and then loop over many `num_value` values and compare the results of the three functions.

Comment: This is an interesting approach. It definitely would make more sense than my code from a real-world application standpoint, and I think definition functions come up in the next section of my readings. But the defined function doesn't seem to account for applying even powers to negative integer roots as a way of being equivalent to the user-entered value.  Is there a particular benefit to doing it that way?

Comment: @Katurday You mean why I for example don't look for (-3)^2? Because that's the same as 3^2. Or do I misunderstand you and you see a case that I'm missing?